# Population size below which tech companies (such as Google, Oracle, Comcast, etc) could no longer operate

Tags: society, apocalypse, population

Let's say that there is some worldwide catastrophe (some zombie-like infection or something else) that affects working age people in such a way that technology companies do not have enough people to sustain daily operations.

As a result, internet service provides, utility (electricity, water, etc.) companies, and IT firms like IBM, Oracle, Google and others would close operations.

How low would the population have to go for this kind of scenario to unfold?

Comment: I guess you would have to first define "daily operations". Their would be different pre- and post-crisis definitions of daily operations. Presumably resources from non-core services would be re-allocated after a crisis, so that operations could continue in a manner that scales down - to a certain extent.

Answer (score 5):

The catastrophe would have to be fairly specific for tech companies to run out of potential employees before they run out of paying customers.

Consider an epidemic that affects all the working population, perhaps because it's spreading through air circulation systems in offices and stores and factories. This would hit the most vital utilities (water, electricity, communications) as well as  food production and distribution (are those utilities?) equally hard. Replacing workers there will be the priority, which would drain the pool of employees for tech companies.

So far, it seems like your scenario might happen. Tech employees might even quit or be drafted by the government to keep utility systems running.

But here is the catch: Any sizable catastrophe that reduces the population and disrupts the economy will divide companies into two groups:

1. Those whose products are now vital and don't need advertising to sell
2. Those whose products are now luxuries, that no amount of advertising will sell.

Google's income will dry up, with the other tech companies not far behind, as their customer base is decimated, with all companies going into survival mode, eliminating any new investments. Amazon will either convert to shipping food overnight or die without ever having made a profit.

So in which scenario might tech companies run out of (talented) employees before customers? It would have to hit tech workers specifically, either through some kind of [Snow Crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_Crash) virus killing them off or maybe a global cyberwar breaks out, causing the governments of the world to forcibly draft all techies for their hacking armies. This would be unrelated to general population levels.

**In either case, the answer to your question seems to be: There is no level of general population decrease that would cause tech companies to have a need of replacement employees.**

In the case of a specific tech-worker-killing catastrophe (an nanotech disaster  wipes out Silicon Valley?), the richer companies will poach employees from the poorer ones, who will shut down eventually.

Edit to answer Sean Boddy:

It's hard to make more than wild guesses, as there are so many unknowns. For example, are tech devices still being shipped from China as normal, or has all international trade been halted/quarantined?

- IBM: May be in a good position to be nationalized or supported by the government to protect critical infrastructure. Love those mainframes!
- Google: Another candidate for government support, as the guardian of our collected knowledge, tasked with securing as much valuable data as they can from collapsing companies. They may also have the innovation and connections required to become the central communications and information hub on the internet, though they will face competition from ISPs and the government.
- Facebook: Has the enviable position of becoming the most likely way people keep in contact with separated family, friends and loved ones. Would need to start charging for access and "find my ..." facial recognition searches.
- Apple: Unlikely to get new hardware from China or sell anything if they do. However, has enough cash reserves to become a bank or anything else.
- Oracle: Business as usual, except now the license audit teams are heavily armed when they visit to collect their dues ;-)

Comment: Well done. +1. If you have more insight into some ways the larger tech companies might diversify into critical markets, I'd love to see them.

Answer (score 1):

As corporeal pointed out in his comment, you have to define daily operations. Does it mean continued improvement as planned, or is it merely to keep the existing configuration running?

I'm less confident about reassigning people. You can't turn an UX designer into an admin overnight. Things to consider:

- Who has the passwords? Even people who *known* how to run the system might be locked out because they're not on the list of people who are allowed to do it. And people who can expand the list are gone.
- Will parts of the infrastructure go offline? Operators elsewhere might be able to cope if a few data centers fail.
- How much daily maintenance is required? Will disks overflow if nobody plugs in new ones?

Answer (score 1):

People are clever and adaptive, and companies are even more clever and adaptive by design.

If there was some sort of large scale elimination of tech personnel, then companies wold adapt very rapidly to survive under the new conditions. In the opening rounds, companies like Google, Amazon or Apple will do better since they already have a very large talent pool (so they will still have a larger number of people working in absolute terms, a 25% reduction of employees at a startup with only 100 people might be a disaster, a 25% reduction of the thousands of Google employees is an inconvenience [except for the people who have extra space in the games rooms]).

In round two, Google, Amazon, Apple and all the other tech giants use their mammoth resources to buy as much help as they can get. Remaining small companies will be bought up not for their IP but for their actual workers. Indian datacenters will be placed on ships and imported. Smart high school kids and hackers will be given giant tech scholarships. This vacuum cleaner effect will be positive in raising the wages of IT workers, and will also result in some downstream effects as schools gear up to turn out new generations of workers and parents and students demand IT courses. (One might speculate about a society 40 years hence overflowing with IT developers but lacking lawyers, doctors and plumbers....)

In round 3, after all the conceivable IT workers have been gathered up, companies will begin to streamline, automate or otherwise find ways to increase the productivity of remaining staff. Low hanging fruit will include jettisoning anything which is not a "core" function, changing internal procedures to remove bottlenecks and eliminating layers of non IT staff. After that, one of the holy grails of the IT industry will be to automate as much as possible. We already see a lot of coding being done by assembling "modules" of pre written code, there could be other valid approaches such as self learning neural networks, running "genetic algorithms" of code to winnow out inefficient ones or even using expert systems (ultimately AI) to write code without human intervention at all.

This process will take place with startling rapidity, rounds one and two will be well underway before the year is out, and the shakeout of the IT industry will be frightening to behold (even medium sized firms like Cisco might fall prey to being dismembered. Who has the resources to fight Apple Inc., with a $35 *billion* dollar dragons horde in their offshore accounts alone?). The process of automation will take more time, as many of these techniques are still experimental at this time, and programmers and IT workers will certainly see the trends and resist them, but the inexorable logic of the markets will compel companies to become more productive, produce marketable products faster and streamline costs or die.